# What is difference between Explainer and Kernelexplainer in SHAP?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, shap

I am new about explainable AI. I started to work on SHAP. When I look at the codes, I am confused. The website is https://towardsdatascience.com/using-shap-values-to-explain-how-your-machine-learning-model-works-732b3f40e137

You can see the code below:

```
# Fits the explainer
explainer = shap.Explainer(model.predict, X_test)
# Calculates the SHAP values - It takes some time
shap_values = explainer(X_test)
```

The other website is https://snyk.io/advisor/python/shap/functions/shap.KernelExplainer

You can see the code below:

```
    # use Kernel SHAP to explain test set predictions
    explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(svm.predict_proba, X_train, nsamples=100, link="logit")
    shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
```

What is the difference? Which one is true? In the first code, X_test is used for explainer. In the second code, X_train is used for kernelexplainer. Why?

Comment: Explainer is a super class, which depending on args -- type of a model and data -- delegates the responsibility to calcualte SHAP values to concrete implementations of an explainer.

Answer (score 1):

An old question but worth answering for new comers. The correct way as far the [SHAP documentation](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is to fit the `Explainer` class on the train set and use that to explain features' contributions to predictions on the test set

So for example:

```py
explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(svc_linear.predict_proba, X_train)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
```